# Custom Checkbox Not Working As Expected

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I'm attempting to create this checkbutton and then call that check button where ever I'd like in my project and have it work by adding an image like it's supposed to but I can't even get it to NSLog...for testing purposes...

Below are the button .h and .m files. and the view that I'm calling the button into and trying to use...

**CheckButton.h**
    #import

```
@interface CheckButton : UIButton {
    BOOL _checked;
}

@property (nonatomic, setter=setChecked:) BOOL checked;

-(void) setChecked:(BOOL)check;

@end
```

**CheckButton.m**

```
#import "CheckButton.h"

@implementation CheckButton
@synthesize checked = _checked;

-(id) init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        self.checked = NO;
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(setChecked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) awakeFromNib {
    self.checked = NO;
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void) setChecked:(BOOL)check{
    _checked = check;
    if(_checked) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         NSLog(@"Checked");
    } else {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         NSLog(@"UnChecked");
    }
}

-(void) OnCheck:(id) sender {
    self.checked = _checked;
}


@end
```

**GoToBedPopUp.h**

```
#import "CheckButton.h"

@interface GoToBedPopup : PopupContainer{
    IBOutlet  CheckButton *checkboxButton;
}

// Checkboxes - (CheckButton)
@property (nonatomic, strong) CheckButton *checkHR;

@end
```

**GoToBedPopUp.m**

```
#import "GoToBedPopup.h"

@implementation GoToBedPopup


@synthesize checkHR, checkO2, checkMovement, checkNoise, checkSkinTemp;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    // Checkbox Button
    checkHR = [[CheckButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17, 31, 23, 23)];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Hi have you checked my answer???

Comment: Yeah I checked it, but was unable to get it to work :(.

Comment: myself it was working fine...

Comment: hi working sample i have attached here https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vsqjxr0uufzc1w/testCheckBox.zip

Comment: Wow you really went over and above building a sample project, thanks for that! Although your version seems to be working fine, mine still isn't. I've merged what yo've sent over but still can't seem to get it to work. I'm also not using interface builder and am calling the button programmatically into a view. Is there anything else that might cause it to not work?

Comment: Have you solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i tested your code every thing okay u just change only one thing....

```
- (void) setChecked:(BOOL)check{
    _checked = !check; //** this is the only one change needed 
    if(_checked) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Check.png"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"Checked");
    } else {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Uncheck.png"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"UnChecked");
    }
}
```

Sample project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vsqjxr0uufzc1w/testCheckBox.zip)